# Choose a battery for variable speed application

Tags: batteries, capacity

I have a simulink model of an electric car supplied by an ideal source and I want to replace the ideal source with a battery model. Is it correct if I integrate the current demanded during the whole period from the ideal source to choose the capacity (Ah)? 
I am kind of confused since the capacity depends on the current demanded and it is not constant.

Comment: Yes, integrate the instantaneous current taken into ampere hours.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Simulink Battery Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/battery.html). Even if you don't have Simulink or this library, the docs here are pretty helpful.

The block diagram (from the mathworks site) shows a primitive battery model update is to simply add an internal resistance, and track capacity (Ah) by integrating instantaneous current.

[image: Simulink's Battery Block]

The docs also have details on much better battery models that include the charge/discharge curves for different battery chemistries. There is even an example to show how to get simulation parameters from battery datasheets.